# Why I have Error 400 or 404 using Spring/Thymeleaf if I have null fields?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Book class fields:

```
    private int id_book;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 120, message = "Name should be between 2 and 120 chars")
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 120, message = "Author should be between 2 and 120 chars")
    private String author;
    @Min(value=1700, message = "Age in diapason between 1700 and 2023") @Max(value=2023, message = "Age in diapason between 1700 and 2023")
    private int year_book;
    private Integer id_person;
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("books", bookDAO.index());
        return "/books/index";
    }
```

DAO:

```
public List index(){
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM book", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Book.class));
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Book list</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book list</h1>
<div th:each="book : ${books}">
  <a th:href="@{/books/{id}(id=${book.getId_book()})}" th:text="${book.getName()}">Name</a></div>
<br/>
<a th:href="@{/books/new}">Add new book</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem: when I have null value in id_person, I have 404 error. When I delete this value, all is good.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UniWL.png)

I tried to swap ints to Integers but there is no result.

Comment: Is there any stacktrace printed on your server to indicate more information about the problem?